# blueprintjs date picker formatting off

Tags: blueprintjs

I'm curious if anyone else using blueprintjs is having trouble getting the date formatter to work?  It comes out looking like this for me.

I initially thought it was conflicting with Bootstrap but am not actually seeing anything that would suggest that it is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was a CSS conflict with the datetime picker library

Comment: Care to elaborate what exactly the conflict was? I have a similar issue with this component.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I just got rid of the datetime picker library and used blueprint instead.

Comment: yeah this screenshot looks like you were missing `blueprint-datetime.css` entirely